# AS3 custom TextField text is being drawn outside its textWidth

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, flashdevelop

So this one is a little hard to explain. I have a custom Text class that automatically resizes and sets the width of the text when you change its value. I then take that Text and draw it on a Bitmap to scale it up to make the text look pixelated.

I have a property called `maxWidth` that allows you to restrict the width of the text if you want it to maintain a certain width. By default the `maxWidth` is the width of the text's parent so that it doesn't get cut off or expand the parent's boundaries unexpectedly.

So unfortunately when I draw the text it sometimes gets cut off on the right side. Now I've checked all the values and the `width` and `textWidth` are showing up as within their `maxWidth` values, but when I take a look myself through screenshots I see the text is actually about 3 pixels wider than it should be.

Here's an image to better explain what I mean:

[image]

I turned on borders so you can easily see what I mean. The word "and" on the first line gets drawn outside its border. Here is the line of code that handles resizing text when you change its bounds.

```
override protected function checkResize(value:String):void {
    var bufferWidth:uint = Math.floor(Number(defaultTextFormat.size) / bufferDivisor) + bufferMin;
    var maxWidth:Number = this.maxWidth;
    x = y = 0;

    if (parent is Stage) {
        var stageParent:Stage = Stage(parent);
        super.width = stageParent.stageWidth;
        super.height = stageParent.stageHeight;

        if (maxWidth == 0) maxWidth = stageParent.stageWidth;
    }
    else {
        super.width = parent.width;
        super.height = parent.height;

        if (maxWidth == 0) maxWidth = parent.width;
    }

    maxWidth = maxWidth / scale;
    text = value;

    if (textWidth + bufferWidth <= maxWidth) super.width = textWidth + bufferWidth;
    else super.width = maxWidth;

    super.height = textHeight + 4;

    if (textSnapshot) updateSnapshot();
    if (alignRelation) Align.alignTo(textSprite, alignRelation, alignDirection, alignXOffset, alignYOffest);
}
```

And for this text specifically the `width` value states it's 512, which is correct since that's the `maxWidth`. However if you notice the top line in the text, it goes beyond the 512 width border, it actually goes all the way to 515 even though it says its `width` is 512. Even more bizarre is the `textWidth` states it's 510.4 even though the first line goes well beyond that amount. I just want to know if I'm doing anything wrong or if there's a way to get a true `textWidth` value.

Comment: We faced a very similar issue in the past, it might be related to the way text bounds recalculation is done by Flash Player. You can try to call the checkResize function twice in two different frames, after the second call the bound should be calculated correctly. Not sure if it's the same case, though. The key point - two different frames, the correct bound would be calculated in the next frame after width was assigned to textfield.

Comment: "in the next frame after *width* was assigned to textfield" - excuse me, after the *value* was assigned, not width.

Comment: I imagine it has something to do with sub-pixels acting screwy. Technically the width is correct because it's staying within the bounds of its parent. Somehow the string is being drawn outside the width border without actually updating the width. Calling checkResize multiple times doesn't seem to do anything unfortunately. The only way around this right now is to mess with the bufferzone, but even then it still manages to cut off another text down the line.

Comment: I have had this exact same issue, I never found the reason. My hack-ey solution was to pad out the width as a percentage of the whole. I also think that the width has something to do with how the width of each font charactor is wrongly measured.

Comment: I found my own hack-ey solution, any time I change the text it gradually reduces the width until the textwidth reduces as well (since the textwidth is adjusted automatically depending on the width), usually this means the longest line wraps around to the next line and draws everything correctly. It's not a perfect solution but it works for now

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to embedding fonts, at least it was when I had the same problem. A workaround is to set the right margin of the text field, like so

```
var tf:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
tf.rightMargin = 10; // or whatever fixes your problem, e.g. relate it to font size
textField.setTextFormat(tf);
```

Comment: I can't verify the validity of this solution so I won't be able to confirm it as the answer but it sounds right since I embedded my fonts initially. I ended up scrapping everything and making a custom character parser that uses bitmap images to form words and it gives pixel-perfect widths while also allowing me to scale the text up to get pixelated. This way I could bypass the Flash renderer and have more control over the code.